# Flattening a Dictionary of Dictionaries With SelectMany()

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have these dictionaries:

```
public class CiscoVSAN
{
    private string _VSANName;
    private string _VSANNum;
    public string VSANName{ get{return _VSANName;} set{_VSANName=value;} }
    public string VSANNum{ get{return _VSANNum;} set{_VSANNum=value;} }

    public Dictionary<int, CiscoSwitch> MemberSwitches = new Dictionary<int, CiscoSwitch>();
}

public Dictionary<int, CiscoVSAN> VSANList = new Dictionary<int, CiscoVSAN>();
```

I am trying to replace this foreach

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, CiscoVSAN> vsanpair in this.VSANList)
{
    var currSwitchAsEnumerable  = vsanpair.Value.MemberSwitches.Where(cs => cs.Value.switchName == RemoteSwitchName);
    if (currSwitchAsEnumerable != null)
    {
        //currVSAN.MemberSwitches.Add(DomainID, currSwitchAsEnumerable.FirstOrDefault().Value);
        currSwitch = currSwitchAsEnumerable.FirstOrDefault().Value;
        break;
    }
}
```

with a SelectMany on the outer Dictionary.  I want the first match in MemberSwitches that matches the condition. Not all VSANs have the same member switches in their respective dictionary. I have tried this:

```
var selectmany = this.VSANList.SelectMany(cs => cs.Value).Where( => cs).Where(cs.Value.SwitchName == RemoteSwitchName).First();
```

and this:

```
var selectmany = this.VSANList.Values.SelectMany(cs => cs.Value).Where( => cs).Where(cs.Value.SwitchName == RemoteSwitchName).First();
```

But each time the compiler tells me it cannot infer the type arguments from usage.  I also tried feeding it a type argument with  after the SelectMany statement but that didn't work either. Most of the examples I looked at either flattened lists of lists or simple dictionaries. They also didn't specify any type on the SelectMany.

Edited to add I tried this:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> mydict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
var selectlist = mydict.Values.SelectMany(n => n).ToList();
```

and did not get the compiler error about inferring type. So then I tried this, just to flatten the dictionary and turn it to a list:

```
var selectmany = this.VSANList.Values.SelectMany(vs => vs).ToList();
```

and I get the compiler warning again.  I am not sure what type to specify or how to specify it.

Comment: That `.Where( => cs)` syntax does not look valid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no typo, you have a syntax error: the part `.Where ( => cs )` is illegal. What did you try to express here?

EDIT:

Actually, to think about it, your entire expression is illegal or mistyped.

The delegate that you pass to SelectMany should return `IEnumerable<T>`, but your expression returns `CiscoVSAN`

Comment: Sorry that should be .Where(cs => cs) I fixed that but still get the message about inferring the type.

Comment: @David: that is still incorrectly typed. The delegate passed to Where() should return a bool.

Comment: Ok... this came from antoher posting here:

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
var selectmany = this.VSANList.Values.SelectMany(vs => vs.MemberSwitches).Where(cs => cs.Value.switchName == RemoteSwitchName).First();
```